# IText7 Remove Header & Footer

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7, pdf-reader

I need to read pdf in my project, I use iText7 for this. The problem is that along with the text, I also get the header and footer, which I don’t need. Can I delete them from the pdf or read the pdf without them?

Comment: hope it may help you to resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582816/itext-7-need-to-skip-reading-page-header-elements

Comment: In the light of the information given in response to the question @Nikita linked: Is the pdf you want to read properly tagged?